# how to insert a greek letter with a greek superscript(with a minus sign behind it) as a lower bound of an integral?

Tags: greek, superscripts

I want to define lower bound of integral as `\Gamma` with superscript `-\varepsilon`.
I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem: can you show us what you've tried that has failed?

Comment: $\int_{\Gamma^\varepsilon}$?

Comment: I think you need `$\int_{\Gamma^{-\varepsilon}}$`. `\[\int_{\Gamma^{-\varepsilon}}\]` might be nicer

Comment: @Zarko Please, write an answer and ping me after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Integral "bounds" -- better say `limits` -- can be nested, for example

```
$\int_{a_{\max}}^{b_{\min}}$
```

In your problem in case of the inline math you can write `$\int_{\Gamma^{-\varepsilon}}$` or in the case of display style:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
    \begin{document}
\[
    \int_{\Gamma^{-\varepsilon}}
        \quad\mathrm{or}\quad   \
    \int\limits_{\Gamma^{-\varepsilon}}
\]
    \end{document}
```

[image]